# Formation of a non-Sol Oort cloud with high mass planets

Tags: planet, astrophysics, oort-cloud, solar-system-evolution

Based on recent developments in astronomy, pertaining to a greater degree of measurement, the mass of the Oort cloud around Sol is apparently only about [1.5 times the mass of earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oort_cloud#Comets), in contrast to over a thousand times, roughly, as previous thought, which got me wondering, if there might be a scenario where an Oort cloud would have substantial mass, and moreover, would consist of planets—full-on planets—rather than ours which consists of a handful of planetoids and a whole lot of comets.

I know the field (of astronomy) is currently evolving, and there's a great deal of unknown aspects regarding the formation of solar systems but one idea I do have is, planetoids drifting through an outer system and being captured upon the stars initial formation, with an outer system with a rather high density of interstellar gas, and so encouraging the formation of said planets.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The gravitational interactions that kick some planetesimals out to very large distances, populating the Oort Cloud, shift the orbits of *planets* by very tiny amounts. So you simply can't produce an Oort Cloud of "full on planets".

Comment: At the distance of the Oort cloud the sun's gravity is so weak, that if you'd put a cloud of Jovians there, their mutual scattering perturbations would quickly depopulate the cloud.

Comment: Article on oort cloud exoplanets https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.11109

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify - the solid materials that make up the inferred Oort cloud were not formed there. They were formed much closer to the star (or another star - see below) and then thrown outwards by interactions with other bodies. Only some fraction of the material that is thrown outwards remains part of the Solar System; much of it will escape.

One of the main theories to explain the structure and dynamics of our Solar System is the ["Nice model"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_model), which has a variant in which an ice-giant planet, similar to Neptune, is ejected outwards after an encounter with Jupiter. If the ejection has a low enough speed, the planet may stay in the Oort cloud and indeed, this is a possible explanation for the presence of a [planet 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Nine) out there somewhere.

I don't think there is any scenario where a cloud of planetary-sized objects forms an Oort cloud. During star formation, the circumstellar disk forming the solids and from which gas can be accreted onto planets is in the inner regions. A [recent study](https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.11109) (thanks sno) shows that even throwing out a single planet, such that it remains in the Oort cloud is an unlikely event (see also [Portegies Zwart 2021](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2021A%26A...647A.136P/abstract)). Capture of the odd planet or two is also possible, but unlikely, although some fraction of the current Oort cloud may be in the form of captured objects [Portegies Zwart et al. 2021](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2021A%26A...652A.144P/abstract)).